# Tabbed Fragment is not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, gradle

I am using a tab fragment to show tab on swipe, but unexpectedly I am getting some error what I cannot understand.

I have 3 tab: Tab1, Tab2, Tab3, but in every case I am getting error in return

> **Error:(25, 24) error: incompatible types: Tab1 cannot be converted to Fragment**

Is there any problem in my gradle or elsewhere?

```
public class Pager extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    int tabcount;

    public Pager(FragmentManager fragmentManager, int tabcount) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.tabcount = tabcount;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                Tab3 tab3 = new Tab3();
                return tab3;
            default:
                Tab2 tab21 = new Tab2();
                return tab21;
        }
    }
}

public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup  container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return super.onCreateView(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
    }

}
```

Comment: add the code of Tab1, Tab2, Tab3..

Comment: I have added code of Tab1 similar to Tab2 & Tab3.

Comment: I have solved the problem in other way. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your imports, make sure you are using support versions of `Fragment` (`android.support.v4.app.Fragment`) and not `android.app.Fragment`.

Comment: I have imported android.support.v4.app.Fragment this in MainActivity

Comment: great! please add the solution, it can help others with the same problem.

Comment: I just used android studio tabbed activity, and it works nicely.